# Visual effects view iOS 9 noise

Tags: ios9, uivisualeffectview, uivibrancyeffect

In iOS 8 everything worked fine and when upgrading to iOS 9 my iPhone shows some vibrancy texts with a noisy edge. It looks horrible but I can't figure out why it does look like that 
[image]